# Use jquery soap client to send and retrieve data from another domain

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, soap, cross-domain

i am developing a system which needs to use jquery soap to send and receive data. we have 3 sites:
1. for the client site with a different domain name.
2. an admin site with another different domain.
3. An api site which has another domain main.
So basically, the api is in between these 2 sites, the 2 sites will just use the api to send and receive data. The scenario will be, the first 2 sites will have no php scripts in it, it's main purpose is for the client and admin showing the datas and sending data to api for it to be saved. The problem that i am encountering is the cross origin, the 2 sites cannot communicate with the api because of the cross origin. Can anyone help me with this? Anyone can show me how can JQUERY or ANGULAR use soap without having problem with it's cross-origin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using jquery $.ajax method. To enable cross domain you will have to mention the following options

```
crossDomain : true,
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Rest will be same.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, how do you call the method on the api from the ajax call? without using any condition on the api?

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   type: 'POST/GET/PUT/DELETE'
   success: function(data){},
});

Comment: i was referring to the api, if i have a method getmethis() in my api, how will i call this method using ajax? without having a condition in my api like if($_POST[data]){ getmethis() }, i want is to automatically call the method in the api, thanks